# how to export dataframes from R to excel and separate them by an empty row

Tags: r, excel, append, export

I should append dataframes stored in different lists in R, and separate them by an empty row (in the excel file).

I can't bind dataframes from different lists in one because they have different numbers of columns.

I can't also use packages 'xlsx' and 'XLConnect' because they give me problems related to Java.

Any help is welcome.

The first list of dataframe:

```
listofdfs <- list(x <- data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011),"b"=c(35,30,20)), y <- data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "b"=c(6,21,40)) )

label <- c("Red","Green")

listofdfs <- setNames(listofdfs, label)

$Red
     y  b
1 2009 35
2 2010 30
3 2011 20

$Green
     y  b
1 2009  6
2 2010 21
3 2011 40
```

the second list of dataframes (with more columns than the previous ones):

```
listofdfs_2 <- list(x <- data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011),"x_1"=c(35,30,20), "x_2"=c(1,2,0), "x_3"=c(6,0,3), "x_4"=c(12,5,8)), y <- data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "x_1"=c(6,21,40), "x_2"=c(3,5,0), "x_3"=c(6,9,12), "x_4"=c(8,5,1)) )

label <- c("Red","Green")

listofdfs_2 <- setNames(listofdfs_2, label)

$Red
     y x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4
1 2009  35   1   6  12
2 2010  30   2   0   5
3 2011  20   0   3   8

$Green
     y x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4
1 2009   6   3   6   8
2 2010  21   5   9   5
3 2011  40   0  12   1
```

I'd like to obtain on the same excel sheet the tables in this way:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `openxlsx`, which I hope works better for you than the other packages you mentioned, you can do:

```
library(openxlsx)

# create your workbook
mywb <- createWorkbook() 

# create the sheets you need based on the first list of tables
for (sheetName in names(listofdfs)){
    addWorksheet(mywb , sheetName )
}

# get all your lists of tables in a single list
l_listOfDF <- mget(ls(pattern="listofdf"))

# initiate the index of the row where you will want to start writing (one per sheet)
startR <- rep(1, length(listofdfs)) ; names(startR) <- names(listofdfs)

# loop over the lists of tables using index and then over the elements / sheets using their names
for(N_myListOfDF in seq(l_listOfDF)){

  for(pageName in names(l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]])){

    # write the name/number of your table in the correct sheet, at the correct row
    writeData(mywb, sheet=pageName, startRow=startR[pageName], paste0("Table ", N_myListOfDF, "."))

    # write your data in the correct sheet at the correct row (the one after the name)
    writeData(mywb, sheet=pageName, startRow=startR[pageName]+1, l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]][[pageName]])
    
    # update the row number (the + 3 is to leave space for name of table, headers and blank row
    startR[pageName] <- startR[pageName]+nrow(l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]][[pageName]]) + 3

  }
}

# save your workbook in a file
saveWorkbook(mywb , "myfile.xlsx")
```

Output file:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One problem at a time:

**1. Appending data frames with different columns**

```
rbind(df1,df2) #this fails if they do not have the same columns

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    bind_rows(df2) #this works even with different columns

#including an empty row
df1 %>%
    bind_rows(df_empty) %>% #pre-create a df with one "check" column and an empty row
    bind_rows(df2)
```

**2.Writing to excel**

If you have tried different packages like `foreign` to do it, simply save as a `csv` which can be opened in Excel.

```r
write.csv(df_result,"result.csv")
```

Comment: I need to append the datasets from the different lists by column, not by rows

Comment: That doesn't match the description in your question. If you ```cbind()```, different columns do not matter, only different number of rows. Additionally there is no way to add empty "rows" between appended columns. Can you extend your problem description with an example of input and output?

Comment: I edited my question with examples of input and output.

Comment: Any idea for a possible solution?